# Complete list of React JSX component properties

Tags: reactjs

Is there any particular website that contains a complete list of properties for all `JSX` components?

For example: `<button>` has `onClick` and much more.

Answer (score 1):

- React exposes list of different SyntheticEvents. You can read all about them [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events)
- Also react has all DOM properties and attributes but they are all should be camelCased. You can read more about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

Also be sure you actually understand difference between JS, `onclick` DOM handler, and React synthetic event `onClick`:

1. JavaScript has nothing to do with DOM `onclick` handler. That API is given to JS by browsers but there are no mention about that handler in ES specification.
2. React has its own synthetic events. They are a little bit different from DOM events. Main difference is that React tried to make them cross-browser.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the clarification, sorry if I was coming off a bit rude in my comment.

Comment: @remoo nw. Everything was fine :)
I hope you have learned something new.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, onClick is an event handler native to JavaScript. As for a ' list of properties ' , I would read the React Docs, [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). Typically you make your own props for JSX components.

Comment: "onClick is an event handler native to JavaScript" - Horribly wrong statement

Comment: My apologies, I was just sharing what I knew. Notice how I put, if I'm not mistaken, I was trying to help OP out. Feel free to correct me rather than just pointing out my flaw in the statement. Thank you for the advice though! :) [here is my reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: I was going to but It was difficult to do in comment section.